# Getting No Urls to Fetch error on Nutch, even though there are Urls to fetch

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am still getting used to Nutch. I managed to get a test crawl going using `bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 6 -topN 10` over `nutch.apache.org` as well as indexing it to solr using: `bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://<domain>:<port>/solr/core1/ -depth 4 -topN 7`

Not even mentioning that it times out on my own site, I can't seem to get it to crawl again, or crawl any other sites (e.g. wiki.apache.org). I have deleted all of the crawl directories in the nutch home directory and I still get the following error (stating that there are no more URLs to crawl):

```
<user>@<domain>:/usr/share/nutch$ sudo sh nutch-test.sh
solrUrl is not set, indexing will be skipped...
crawl started in: crawl 
rootUrlDir = urls
threads = 10
depth = 6
solrUrl=null
topN = 10
Injector: starting at 2013-07-03 15:56:47
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: finished at 2013-07-03 15:56:50, elapsed: 00:00:03
Generator: starting at 2013-07-03 15:56:50
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: true
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 10
Generator: jobtracker is 'local', generating exactly one partition.
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
Stopping at depth=0 - no more URLs to fetch.
No URLs to fetch - check your seed list and URL filters.
crawl finished: crawl
```

My `urls/seed.txt` file has `http://nutch.apache.org/` in it.

My `regex-urlfilter.txt` has `+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*nutch.apache.org//([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*` in it.

I have also increase the `-depth` and `topN` to specify that there is more to index, but it always gives the error after the first crawl. How do I reset it so that it crawls again? Is there some cache of URLs that needs to be cleaned out somewhere in Nutch?

**UPDATE**: It seems the problem with our site was that I was not using `www`, it did not resolve without `www`. By a `ping`, www.ourdomain.org does resolve.

But i have put this into the necessary files and there is still a problem. Primarily it looks like `Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1` is the problem across the board, but was not on the first crawl. Why and what filter is rejecting the URL, it should not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks this is embarrassing. But the old nutch-not-crawling-because-it's-dismissining-urls addage of 'check your `*-urlfilter.txt`' file applies here.

In my case i had an extra `/` in the url regex:

`+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*nutch.apache.org//([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*`

should have been `+^http://([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\.)*nutch.apache.org/([a-z0-9\-A-Z]*\/)*`

Comment: Ahem, I had a space before + I couldn't spot. Then I found your answer and checked it again and bam it works now.